# Fix description of website on Google Search result

Tags: seo

So I have a website which is made by using Wordpress platform. I'm completely unaware of SEO and when I search for my website on Google the description is something like this

> A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

My Wordpress robots.txt file content is as follows

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Sitemap: http://www.loadsofshoes.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.loadsofshoes.com/sitemap-images.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Content of robots.txt is right. Site should be indexed. Probably some time ago indexation was prohibited in WordPress settings.

What you can do, request re-indexing of your site in Google Search Console and in some time (one week maybe) you can see usual description of your pages in Google search results.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have uploaded your sitemap.xml?  I have just checked the URL and the page cannot be found.  If you are not familiar with sitemap.xml files, and/or want to 'start as you mean to go on' with SEO, you may find a Plugin such as the 'All in One SEO Pack' or 'Yoast' of interest.

Have you tried just placing:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

in your robot.txt file?